# Unknown column 'DISCRIMINATOR' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run an example of `Inheritance type SINGLE TABLE` in `Hibernate`. However While persisting `cat` and `dog` I am getting the below error:

```
Unknown column 'DISCRIMINATOR' in 'field list'
```

Below are my entities

**Animal**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Animal")

public abstract class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    int id;
    String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public abstract void makeNoise();




}
```

**Dog**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Dog") 

public class Dog extends Animal{

    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
System.out.println("woof woof");        
    }

}
```

**Cat**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Cat") 
public class Cat extends Animal {





    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
System.out.println("meow meow");        
    }

}
```

**DDL for Animal**

```
insert into Animal (name,DISCRIMINATOR) values (?, 'Cat')
```

Comment: Could you please provide a DDL of your  `Animal` table.

Comment: @SternK, updated the question

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Try to remove `@DiscriminatorValue("Animal")` from the `Animal` class and instead of `@DiscriminatorValue(value="Cat")` use `@DiscriminatorValue("Cat")` and the same for the `Dog`.

Comment: @SternK, did that but still the same issue. I am using Hibernate version 5.1

Comment: @ghostrider did you find a solution for this problem?